# Hadoop job only running on LocalJobRunner

Tags: java, hadoop

Hadoop beginner here. I have the following run and main methods:

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Job job = new Job();

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.submit();
    return 0;
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Tool myTool = new Extractor();
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.set("mapred.job.tracker", "<IP>:9001");
    config.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://<IP>:9000");

    myTool.setConf(config);
    ToolRunner.run(myTool, new String[]{"<file>.json", "output"});
 }
```

For some reason, this is running just fine, but only on the local machine. This is being run directly out of eclipse. Although the job tracker is technically on the same box, it is never receiving any jobs. What is wrong with my configuration?

The core-site.xml is:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.default.name</name>
                <value>hdfs:/<IP>:9000</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: paste the content of core-site.xml?

Comment: Ok, it has been included in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you submitting your job.

You client might not be reading correct config file. Make sure you have something like this on your mapred-site.xml. Since you are passing this from your code, it should be fine.

```
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:8021</value>
  </property>
```

And also make sure you are not passing

```
-Dmapred.job.tracker=local
```

when you run the job

And create your config in run method so that you can do.

**Job job = new Job(conf);**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is being run by Eclipse. The mapred-site.xml looks fine, and we are not passing that argument into "VM arguments".

Comment: You  are not setting your config object to job. Verify that "mapred.job.tracker" is correct before submitting the job.

Comment: Since map/reduce 2 : you should use : mapreduce.jobtracker.address